# How would I find the minimal polynomial over the totally imaginary numbers?

Tags: field-theory, minimal-polynomials

For example, say we wanted to find the minimal polynomial of $4+2i$ over the totally imaginary numbers. I attempted this:
$x = 4+2i$.
Then $x+(2i)^2-2i = 0.$
Is my line of thinking correct?

Comment: A minimal polynomial of a number is defined with respect to a field that number is an element of. What field are you referring to when you say "the totally imaginary numbers"? If that field is $\Bbb Q(i)$ or $\Bbb C$, then $x$ is already in that field, so the minimal polynomial will indeed be of degree $1$. But $i\Bbb Q$ and $i\Bbb R$ are not fields, so it doesn't make sense to ask about minimal polynomials over those sets. (Note that the leading coefficient of the polynomial you wrote down is $1$, which is not imaginary.)

Comment: the usual calculation would be $x = 4 + 2 i,$  $x-4 = 2i, $  $x^2 - 8x + 16 = -4,$  $x^2 - 8x + 20 = 0$